# How can McAffee cause a crash on my Macbook Air after being uninstalled?

Tags: macos, crash

I was required to install McAfee antivirus software on my Mac by an employer. When I finished that job, I uninstalled the software. About six months later, my Mac has started to freeze occasionally. I used the Console to find a crash log, copied below, which suggests that McAfee is causing this. Please could anybody suggest a cure?

````
Path:                  /usr/local/McAfee/fmp/bin/fmpd
Identifier:            fmpd
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
Responsible:           fmpd [85698]
User ID:               0

Date/Time:             2020-02-04 [redacted]
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.5 (18F132)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        [redacted]

Sleep/Wake UUID:       [redacted]
Time Awake Since Boot: 180000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       9400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/McAfee/fmp/lib

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /Library/McAfee/*/libeventwriter.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/McAfee/fmp/bin/fmpd
  Reason: image not found```
````

Comment: [This page](https://its.sfsu.edu/guides/mcafeevirusscanmac97) at SFSU may provide some clues as to what to do. There is an uninstaller script tucked away in /Library/McAfee/cma you need to run as root.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions are offered by this page in the McAfee documentation: https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB88461. The first solution is similar to the one in the link in IconDaemon's comment, and it didn't work for me. I have tried the second solution (boot in safe mode, and remove the listed McAfee files) and will post a comment if I continue to have the problem.